# The read function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to the Haskell language and I having some issues with the read function.
Precisely, I understand that:

```
read "8.2" + 3.8
```

Should return 12.0 because we want to return the same type as the second member.
The thing that I don't really get is why does:

```
read "True" || False
```

Return True ? Ok, it returned the same type as False, which is Boolean, but what I don't understand is why the first member. I think I have a vague idea, like, the return function in this case will return the first member because the condition is || ?
Please help me out. Also, I am sorry if this is just basic for most of you guys, but I really want to undersand it.

Comment: well `True OR anything` **is** `True` ;) ... (it does *not* return the first member but the result of the or-operation - try `read "True" && False` if you like)

Comment: Thank you! I had the same thought, just needed someone to clarify this for me. Thank you again.

Comment: np - I guess it's as good as an answer as there could be(?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Follow along in ghci!

```
Prelude> let x = read "True"
Prelude> :t x
x :: Read a => a
```

So `x` doesn't have a concrete type. `x` is sort of an expression that can *provide* a value of a concrete type, when we ask for it. We could ask `x` to be an `Int` or a `Bool` or anything we want. In particular:

```
Prelude> x :: Bool
True
```

We could also ask it to be an `Int`:

```
Prelude> x :: Int
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

But it fails to become one.

So in your code snippet, when did we ask it to become something?

```
Prelude> :t (||)
(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
```

The function `(||)` expects a `Bool`, so it asks its arguments to become `Bool`s. And as we already saw, when we ask `x` to become a `Bool`, it becomes the `Bool` value `True`. So saying:

```
Prelude> x || False
True
```

Is just like saying:

```
Prelude> True || False
True
```

And `(||)` represents [the logical OR operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction), so the result is `True`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 4):

well `True OR anything` **is** `True`

it does *not* return the first member but the result of the or-operation

you should try

```
read "True" && False
```

to see the difference

---

maybe a slight remark/addition:

In a sense you where right that it returns the first *component* - but only because `True || _ = True` so even `True || undefined` is ok:

```
Prelude> read "True" || undefined
True
```

Comment: Oh, ok, I had it all wrong about the read function. Thank you, again.